# How to exclude everything after an @ in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to sql and I'm writing a sql script to select data and the results will be displayed in a .csv format. For one of the fields, I'm needing to select only what is before the @ in the email address for everyone in the listing. I'm not wanting to update the records in the table.

Ex: john.doe@yahoo.com

I'm only needing to select the john.doe

I need assistance please in doing this. I'm using sqlplus in a Linux environment.

Here's now what I have as part of the script. I still need assistance with getting the desired output.

(select nvl(c.email_email_address, ' ')

```
    from email c, person a
    where c.email_pidm = a.person_pidm and
          PERSON.ID = a.person_id and
          c.email_emal_code = 'EMPL' and
          c.email_status_ind = 'A' and
          c.rowid = (select max(b.rowid)
                                   from email b
                                   where b.email_pidm = a.person_pidm and
                                         b.email_emal_code = 'EMP'
                                   and b.email_status_ind = 'A')
                                                                    ) "Employee_Email_Address",
SELECT SUBSTR(email_email_address, 0, INSTR(email_email_address, '@')-1) 
--(select nvl(c.email_email_address, ' ')
        from email c, person a
        where c.email_pidm = a.person_pidm and
              PERSON.ID = a.person_id and
              c.email_emal_code = 'EMP' and
              c.email_status_ind = 'A' and
              c.rowid = (select max(b.rowid)
                                       from email b
                                       where b.email_pidm = a.person_pidm and
                                             b.email_emal_code = 'EMPL'
                                       and b.email_status_ind = 'A')
                                                                        ) "Username"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT SUBSTR('test@example.com', 1, INSTR('test@example.com', '@')-1) FROM DUAL;`

Output:

> test

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
select SUBSTR("test@testdomain.com", 1, INSTR("test@testdomain.com", "@")-1)
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, 0, INSTR(FIELD_NAME, '@')-1) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

SUBSTR works like this:

```
SUBSTR( string, start_position, [ length ] )
```

The length parameter is what ...`INSTR(FIELD_NAME, '@')-1`... is putting in for you.

INSTR tells you where in the string (or field) the character you're looking or is found.  You have to -1 that result, so the '@' doesn't show-up in your return value.

Comment: Although the DB engine will automatically convert the 0 to a 1 for you, it is probably worth noting that in Oracle, strings are 1-based not 0-based.